# Imagine the SQL GROUP BY statement

Tags: sql, database, group-by

I have a Problem with the GROUP BY statement. I understand how it works and what it will do, but i cant imagine it in my brain (i hope this doesnt sound too weird). I learn by imagination but the GROUP BY is somehow weird for me.

So the followup looks like: FROM->WHERE->GROUP BY->HAVING->SELECT ....

Lets say i have a database "children names" and their "parent names". So there are some "parent name"s that have more than one children of course.

In the moment where the group by happens what exactly happens to the table ? All Elements of one group will put together into 1 line right ? But when i have only 1 line left, how can the SELECT that come afterwards still COUNT something ? Its kinda hart to explain what exactly my point is. 
When i use SELECT * it will show me only 1 line per group. When i use SELECT COUNT(whatever) it will give me 1 line but the correct count of group members. But isnt the group already 1 line before the SELECT happens ? 
Im kinda want to imagine this process thats all

Comment: During aggregation `GROUP BY` aggregates (COUNT/MAX/MIN/SUM) are calculated, not at `SELECT` phase.

Comment: Ah, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to think about how the `group by` processes data, you can think of the following mechanism.  I want to emphasize that the actually processing might be quite different; this is for illustration.

1. The table is sorted by the `group by` keys.
2. All rows with the same key are considered as a unit.
3. The `group by` keys for the unit then define one row in the result set.
4. The remaining columns are summarized from the rows in set that matches those rows.

To illustrate this:

```
key value
a     1
b     1
a     2
```

Consider the query:

```
select key, count(*), sum(value)
from t
group by key;
```

First step sort:

```
key value
a     2  -- only the key is considered for the sort, the remaining columns are not
a     1
b     1
```

Break into units:

```
key value
a     2  -- only the key is considered for the sort, the remaining columns are not
a     1
-------
b     1
```

Define the result set rows:

```
Original table          Result set
key value               key
a     2                  a
a     1                  b
-------
b     1
```

Add the calculations for the remaining columns:

```
Original table          Result set
key value               key  count(*)   sum(value)
a     2                  a     2           3
a     1                  b     1           1
-------
b     1
```

I need to emphasize that this is conceptual -- and one valid way of implementing the `group by`.  However, SQL queries *describe* the result set, not the specific processing used to generate it.

Comment: Thank you very much, that actually helps a lot!